# Symfony2 twig code doesn't work in xml template as it works in html

Tags: php, html, xml, symfony, twig

why twig code `{% set code = code(_self) %}` doesn't work in xml template.

```
<!-- src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/hello.xml.twig -->
<hello>
    <name>{{ name }}</name>
</hello>
{% set code = code(_self) %}
```

like it works in html template.

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title "Hello " ~ name %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% set code = code(_self) %}
```

Comment: What is supposed to do your custom Twig function `code` ?

Comment: `{% set code = code(_self) %}` is usefull in displaying Controller Code and Template Code used for the same route

Comment: And what do you mean by does not work ? You get an exception ?

Comment: @COil doesn't work means, its not showing the Controller Code and Template Code when used in xml template. No, i am not getting any exception.
i just want to show those Codes as well when xml template is rendered.

Comment: Can you join the code of your `code` Twig function ?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get, what do you mean by joining the code ?

Comment: What is the content of your `function code() { ...` ?

Comment: its inbuilt function of symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not a native Twig extension it's an additional extension provided by the `DemoBundle` of the Symfony2 standard edition (https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/master/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/Extension/DemoExtension.php). I've just tested and it works but this `code()` Twig extension is only intended to be used in an HTML template not an XML one. If you show the source of you XML template you will see the output of your controller but it will not show up as the generated XML becomes invalid. If you really want the output, you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<code>{{ code(_self) | escape }}</code>
```